# How do I move an object in c++/opengl to a new place and erase the old object

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making Pacman game in opengl and I want to move my pacman in the game represented by a matrix.

The matrix have 16x16 and i put 4's when I whant to draw the walls, 3 for the small spheres and 2 for the pacman.

In the main class of my project I read a key from keyboard and i send the information to the class I defined the game. In that class I have this function:

```
void boardGame::refreshPacman(int n, int m)
{

    int x, y;


    (* pacman).movePacman(n, m); // This is working, it send information to class Pacman. In there I store the n (x axe) and m(y axe), and i get the next coordinates where pacman should translate.


    x = (* pacman).getPacX(); // get coordinate of the old pacman
    y = (* pacman).getPacY(); // get coordinate of the old pacman

    board[x][y] = 0; // delete old information of pacman in matrix 

    x += n; // set the coordinates of x axis for new pacman
    y += m; // set the coordinates of y axis for new pacman

    wall[x][y] = 2; // insert the information of new pacman in matrix

    pac->redraw (x, y, 0.5); // construct the new pacman
}
```

Pacman It's not beeing erased. Can you tell me what do I need to do next, and waht am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you're deleting the pacman when moving it.  Surely you should just pacman->setPacX() and pacman->setPacY(), on the same Pacman object?

Comment: I tried to delete it because i couldnt translate it... when I translate it he simple creates another pacman...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `->` operator with class pointers.

```
(* pacman).movePacman(n, m);
```

Should be:

```
pacman->movePacman(n,m);
```

To erase the earlier pacman, try redrawing the screen before adding the new one. Also, does the pacman destructor internally also end the rendering of the pacman image/sprite?

Comment: I defined pacman as being a sphere. It's my first project in c++, I dont know very well how to work with the destructor since I worked before only with java and c. I read that destructor free the allocation of memory but since i dont understand it well i left it void.

Comment: to redraw the screen, the better way to do that is to create a new and subtitute for the old one?

Comment: While good advice, this doesn't answer the question of how to redraw the screen, which is the issue at hand (no downvote, just commenting).

Answer (score 4):

> Pacman It's not beeing erased. Can you tell me what do I need to do next, and waht am I doing wrong?

OpenGL is not a scenegraph (this is becomming the one statement I'm apparently make in almost every answer). It's a drawing API, which allows you to draw dancy points, lines and triangles. There's no concept of "geometric objects".

If you change something: Clear the old picture and draw a new one!

Comment: I try to erase it  but it's not working... my pacman class, the constructor save the x and y coordinate, the speed and pacman's life. And in pacman's class I have a function  that draws a pacman (basically a sphere). The problem is when i call: pacman->draw(); it draws new pacman's but dont erase the old one's

Comment: To clear a drawing created with OpenGL call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`